# How can I be notified of a VCS issue on a team city build server?

Tags: teamcity

I have a teamcity server configured for CI. Our svn connection occasionally drops, once this happens a project will no longer check for changes, but we are not warned about this without logging onto the servers' web page.

Is there a way to be notified when there is a VCS problem in Team City?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure, but teamcity does have an extensive API and if I understand it right you should be able to get the information from that. I haven't used it yet, just tested it does work. Hope that may help!

Answer (score 2):

Do you use mail notification on you builds?   If so, you can set it to be notified of "Build fails to start".  There may be different reasons to fail, but for us, it is always losing connectivity to VCS server.

- [Subscribing to Notifications](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Subscribing+to+Notifications)
- [Failed to Start Builds](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+State#BuildState-FailedtoStartBuilds)

[image: "Build fails to start" setting]